# How to correctly initialize subclass in Python (parent class being SQLAlchemy Table)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to python and currently I am trying to initialize subclass Cpty with SQLAlchemy engine as a single attribute (I want the other attributes to be set up in parent classes)

I have this setup:

defaultTable.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData

class Default_table(Table):

    def __init__(self, table_name, autoload, autoload_with):
        metadata = MetaData(schema='dbo')
        super(Default_table, self).__init__(table_name, metadata, autoload=autoload, autoload_with=autoload_with)

    def output(self):
        print('ahoj')
```

counterparty.py

```py
from .default_table import Default_table

class Cpty(Default_table):

    def __init__(self, engine):
        table_name = 'CPTY'
        autoload = True
        super(Cpty, self).__init__(table_name, autoload=autoload, autoload_with=engine)
```

and now I want to initialize the the `Cpty` Class, where connection.engine is SQLAlchemy engine

```py
cpty = Cpty(connection.engine)
```

I receive Exception - TypeError

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Table() takes at least two positional-only arguments 'name' and 'metadata'
```

I understand that I do not initialize the Table class with correct set of attributes, but I can not find out, how should I handle this problem as I am quite new to the python.

I expect that by initializind `cpty = Cpty(engine)` that a class Table is initialized with attributes defined in parent `__init__` functions

Comment: Inheritance is not the best way to do this, in my view.  Inheritance expresses IS-A relationships between parent and child.  A connection engine is not a table.  Composition is a better idea here.

Comment: Did you intend for `Cpty` to inherit from `Default_Table` (which creates its own metadata) rather than `Table` (which needs you to provide the metadata)?

Comment: `super(City, self).__init__` invokes `Table.__init__`, and you are providing it with the metadata the way `super(Default_table, self).__init__` does.